# coreOS: force cloud-config to run update-ca-certificates before docker.service

Tags: systemd, coreos

I'm trying to get coreOS to run `update-ca-certificates` before docker is started. It is also fine if `update-ca-certificates`runs and then docker is immediately restarted afterwards.

I've created a new unit in cloud-config:

```
- name: updatecertificates.service
  command: start
  content: |
    [Unit]
    Description=Update the certificates w/ self-signed root CAs
    Before=docker.service

    [Service]
    ExecStart=/usr/sbin/update-ca-certificates
    RemainAfterExit=yes
    Type=oneshot
```

It does run but not before `docker.service` as I need.

I've tried modifying the `docker.service` unit but without any success at even getting the docker daemon to start.

Any ideas on how to enforce `updatecertificates` to run in the correct order or how to restart the docker service after `updatecertificates` activates?

Answer (score 0):

Same problem here but I realized this unit already exists:

```
core@worker-1 ~ $ systemctl cat update-ca-certificates.service 
# /usr/lib64/systemd/system/update-ca-certificates.service
[Unit]
Description=Update CA bundle at /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt
# Since other services depend on the certificate store run this early
DefaultDependencies=no
Wants=systemd-tmpfiles-setup.service clean-ca-certificates.service
After=systemd-tmpfiles-setup.service clean-ca-certificates.service
Before=sysinit.target
ConditionPathIsReadWrite=/etc/ssl/certs
# Do nothing if update-ca-certificates has never been run before
ConditionPathIsSymbolicLink=!/etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt

[Service]
Type=oneshot
ExecStart=/usr/sbin/update-ca-certificates --skip-rehash
```

Try this:

```
- name: "update-ca-certificates.service"
  drop-ins:
   - name: 50-rehash-certs.conf
     content: |
      [Unit]
      ConditionPathIsSymbolicLink=

      [Service]
      ExecStart=
      ExecStart=/usr/sbin/update-ca-certificates
```